# SQL - display nothing if a condition isn't respected

Tags: mysql, select, conditional-statements

I use this query to return me some information :

```
select tick.ticketid 'Ticket', tick.subject 'Sujet', FROM_UNIXTIME(tick.dateline)     'Reception', FROM_UNIXTIME(logs1.dateline) 'Verification', FROM_UNIXTIME(logs2.dateline)     'Debut trait.',
FROM_UNIXTIME(logs3.dateline) 'Fin trait.', tick.prioritytitle 'Priorite',  tick.tickettypetitle 'Genre', tick.timeworked/60 'Temps de travail', tick.fullname  'Createur'
from swtickets tick, swticketauditlogs logs1, swticketauditlogs logs2, swticketauditlogs logs3
where tick.ticketid = logs1.ticketid 
and tick.ticketid = logs2.ticketid
and tick.ticketid = logs3.ticketid
and logs1.actionmsg like '%to: Pre-analysis%'
and (logs2.actionmsg like '%to: Handled%' or logs2.actionmsg like '%to: In Progress%')
and (logs3.actionmsg like '%to: Pre-closed%' or logs3.actionmsg like '%to: Closed%')
group by tick.ticketid
```

I select 3 times the swticketauditlogs table because, for each line of my query, I need three times the same column of the table but with other conditions.

My problem is that with this code, if one of the three conditions on the table swticketauditlogs isn't respected, the ticket is not selected. What I want is :

The ticket is selected and the fields with unrespected condition are blank.

But I can't figure how to do this...

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `LEFT JOIN`s:

```
select tick.ticketid 'Ticket', tick.subject 'Sujet', FROM_UNIXTIME(tick.dateline)     'Reception', FROM_UNIXTIME(logs1.dateline) 'Verification', FROM_UNIXTIME(logs2.dateline)     'Debut trait.',
FROM_UNIXTIME(logs3.dateline) 'Fin trait.', tick.prioritytitle 'Priorite',  tick.tickettypetitle 'Genre', tick.timeworked/60 'Temps de travail', tick.fullname  'Createur'
from
swtickets tick
    left join
swticketauditlogs logs1
    on
      tick.ticketid = logs1.ticketid and
      logs1.actionmsg like '%to: Pre-analysis%'
    left join
swticketauditlogs logs2
    on
      tick.ticketid = logs2.ticketid and
      (logs2.actionmsg like '%to: Handled%' or logs2.actionmsg like '%to: In Progress%')
    left join
swticketauditlogs logs3
    on
      tick.ticketid = logs3.ticketid and
      (logs3.actionmsg like '%to: Pre-closed%' or logs3.actionmsg like '%to: Closed%')
group by tick.ticketid
```

Left joins produce nulls in the columns from the right table, if the join doesn't succeed. (Note that these *are* nulls, not "blank" - whatever that may mean).

Comment: I thought it was around the left joins but I've got difficulties using it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You will have to replace you implicit joins by explicit [`LEFT JOIN`s](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29):

```
...
FROM swtickets tick
LEFT JOIN swticketauditlogs logs1
       ON (     logs1.ticketid = tick.ticketid
            AND logs1.actionmsg LIKE '%to: Pre-analysis%'
          )
LEFT JOIN swticketauditlogs logs2
       ON 
...
```

If a record is found, the values are returned, otherwise your selected columns are `NULL`.

Comment: I thought it was around the left joins but I've got difficulties using it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [outer joins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Outer_joins) (which don't eliminate non-matching rows from other tables):

```
SELECT
  tick.ticketid                 AS `Ticket`,
  tick.subject                  AS `Sujet`,
  FROM_UNIXTIME(tick.dateline)  AS `Reception`,
  FROM_UNIXTIME(logs1.dateline) AS `Verification`,
  FROM_UNIXTIME(logs2.dateline) AS `Debut trait.`,
  FROM_UNIXTIME(logs3.dateline) AS `Fin trait.`,
  tick.prioritytitle            AS `Priorite`,
  tick.tickettypetitle          AS `Genre`,
  tick.timeworked/60            AS `Temps de travail`,
  tick.fullname                 AS `Createur`
FROM
  swtickets AS tick
  LEFT JOIN swticketauditlogs AS logs1 ON (
         logs1.ticketid = tick.ticketid
    AND  logs1.actionmsg LIKE '%to: Pre-analysis%'
  )
  LEFT JOIN swticketauditlogs AS logs2 ON (
         logs2.ticketid = tick.ticketid
    AND (logs2.actionmsg LIKE '%to: Handled%'
     OR  logs2.actionmsg LIKE '%to: In Progress%')
  )
  LEFT JOIN swticketauditlogs AS logs3 ON (
         logs3.ticketid = tick.ticketid
    AND (logs3.actionmsg LIKE '%to: Pre-closed%'
     OR  logs3.actionmsg LIKE '%to: Closed%')
  )
GROUP BY tick.ticketid
```

Comment: I thought it was around the left joins but I've got difficulties using it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Use `LEFT JOIN`s:

```
select ...
from swtickets tick
left join swticketauditlogs logs1 on tick.ticketid = logs1.ticketid and logs1.actionmsg like '%to: Pre-analysis%'
left join swticketauditlogs logs2 on tick.ticketid = logs2.ticketid and (logs2.actionmsg like '%to: Handled%' or logs2.actionmsg like '%to: In Progress%')
left join swticketauditlogs logs3 on tick.ticketid = logs3.ticketid and (logs3.actionmsg like '%to: Pre-closed%' or logs3.actionmsg like '%to: Closed%')
group by tick.ticketid
```

Comment: I thought it was around the left joins but I've got difficulties using it. Thanks a lot!